# How to use UserResource for Jdbi in Dropwizard

Tags: java, dropwizard, jdbi

I'm setting up a Dropwizard project that leverages a mysql database.  I'm starting fairly basically, using the example code on the Dropwizard site itself (found [here](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.5/docs/manual/jdbi3.html#man-jdbi3)).  However, my code fails to compile because it is unable to locate the class UserResource.

Is this a dependency that I'm supposed to be pulling from somewhere?  My pom pulls in version 1.3.5 of dropwizard-core and dropwizard-jdbi3.  Is there something else missing?  Or is "UserResource" a placeholder for a resource class that I am supposed to implement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, UserResource is just an example of a resource one might implement, it's not part of the Dropwizard library